# Dynamic dropdown menu in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, drop-down-menu, frontend

Let's say I have a database table called Teachers.  Each row in the table has a name attribute and I want to display a dropdown menu in my webapp that displays all the names of the teachers in the database.  How can I do this?  I get how I would display a regular dropdown menu, but I don't get how to display one based off of the database.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you would get the teachers:

`@teachers = Teacher.all`

Then in your view, you can display them with:

`select("teacher", "name", @teachers.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true })`

Comment: How exactly would you place that in the view?  Inside a div? Is there any special tag?  Also, what do "teacher", "name" indicate?   

I don't want to place this in a separate form file, because it's not really a form.  I just need the user to pick a choice.